# Windows phone 8.1 runtime apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Hello am developing a wp8.1 runtime app in c# and xaml and I have many pages. So on launching the app, I would like to set a random page to launch up and not the main page. And I would also like to deny one page not to launch randomly

Comment: OK. Please describe what you've tried, what you're having issues with etc. Using a random number generator or something else?

Comment: You can create a List<Frame> where you can add all your pages and select a random index and then display that page. You can exempt your page by not adding it to this collection.

Answer (score 0):

To change your root/default page First open App.xaml.cs class then change your rootFrame name MainPage to your frame name.

```
 if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))               
 {

 throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");

  }
```

It will change your root Frame.